Existence of degree n polynomial best approximation implies existence of degree n+1 best approximation polynomial
I am a highschool student and I have encountered this problem during my working through the book Mathematical analysis by V. Zorich.
Let $P_n(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $n$ and $f:[a,b] \to \Bbb R$ a bounded function.
Define $$\Delta(P_n) = \sup_{x\in[a,b]}|f(x) -P_n(x)| \ \ \mathrm{and} \ \ E_n(f) =\inf_{P_n} \Delta(P_n),$$ the latter being taken over all polynomials of degree $n$. A polynomial is called a polynomial of best approximation of $f$ if $\Delta(P_n) = E_n(f)$
The full question is:
$a)$ show a polynomial of best approximation of degree $0$ exists;
$b)$ among the polynomials $Q_{\lambda}(x)$ of the form $\lambda P_n(x)$, where $P_n$ is a fixed polynomial, there is a polynomial $Q_{\lambda_0}$ such that $$\Delta(Q_{\lambda_0}) = \min_{\lambda \in \Bbb R}\Delta(Q_{\lambda}).$$
The question I am on is:
$c)$ if there exists a polynomial of approximation of degree $n$, there also exists a polynomial of best approximation of degree $n + 1$.
And here are the identical questions asked in MSE.
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7883/there-exist-a-degree-n1-polynomial-of-best-approximation-if-there-exist-a-deg
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/765795/if-there-exists-a-polynomial-of-best-approximation-of-degree-n-there-also-exist
I have also asked a question on MSE myself(it has been answered by Willie Wong):
Existence of degree n polynomial best approximation implies existence of degree n+1 best approximation polynomial by using numerical methods
I have tried the problem for 2 weeks until now, Although the questions asked above has an identical reasoning, but no verified approach had been given, at least using suitable methods as of consideration of the text's level. I have put a question in MSE but nobody answered. So I hereof put it here.
Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

The question is unclear. Please include the reference to MSE.

@AlexandreEremenko Thanks for letting me know, I added it.

Why "numerical methods" and why tag "numerical-analysis"? You are asking for a proof, no?

The problem with asking your question here is that (a) most people here are not familiar with what "suitable methods as of consideration of the text's level" are, not having read the book in question and (b) the obvious way (to a research mathematician) to prove the claim (given a continuous function $f$ on $[a,b]$ and a degree $n$, there exists at least one polynomial of degree at most $n$ that best approximates $f$ in the uniform norm) is probably not matching the desired level you seek.

@WillieWong I am asking for a easy and simple proof. I thought it might be helpful to tag it numerical methods, and now it seems it wouldn't. I will edit my question, thank you.

The problem is that "easy and simple" is in the eye of the beholder. Since you mentioned the level of the text: in the particular chapter it appears to me that Zorich has only dealt with functions of a single variable. Whereas to me the simplest proof does not go through induction but uses multivariable concepts. // Please also: (a) link to the question you yourself asked on MSE and (b) edit the question so we can read the question statement without going to another webpage. Thx.

@WillieWong Thank you, I edited it.
